# mysql: how do I find each row that has the highest value from another column?

Tags: sql, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a database with several tables containing scores and other statistics from games my friends and I play.

I'd like to find the winner (highest score) for every match based on whichever mapname we're looking at.

The two relevant tables look like this (massively trimmed down):

```
matches:
+----------------+---------+
| match_id       | mapname |
+----------------+---------+
| 20200828205505 | jul16   |
| 20200909214044 | jul16   |
| 20200909214901 | jul16   |
| 20200917233839 | jul16   |
| 20200923225809 | jul16   |
+----------------+---------+
players:
+----------------+-----------------+-------+
| match_id       | player_name     | score |
+----------------+-----------------+-------+
| 20200917233839 | Player1         |    11 |
| 20200917233839 | Player2         |    25 |
| 20200923225809 | Player2         |    27 |
| 20200923225809 | Player3         |    19 |
| 20200923225809 | Player1         |    15 |
+----------------+-----------------+-------+
```

In matches, the match_id is unique (it's simply the date), but players will obviously have multiple rows for a given match_id.

So for a given mapname, I want to find every match_id and only retrieve the player_name who has the highest score for each match_id, e.g., the winner for each match.  Using the above, Player2 won both matches. Ultimately I am trying to get win totals for each player for a given map.

So in a nutshell, based on the map jul16, if I have five match_ids, I'd like to get the top score for each one.  I've tried a few things with joins, but I don't know how to find the single row (highest score) for every match_id.  I'm hoping this can be done in one select so I don't have to hand-code it / piece it together with multiple select queries in php.  If I'm going about this incorrectly I'm very interested in knowing alternatives!

All help is very appreciated.

The closest I could get is using a join statement but it only gives me one result (limit 1) vs. the five matches in the example.